# In pandas dataframe handling object data type

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm tearing my hair out a bit with this one. I've imported two csv's into pandas dataframes both have a column called SiteReference i want to use pd.merge to join dataframes using SiteReference as a key.

Initial merged failed as pd.read took different interpretations of the SiteReference values, in one instance 380500145.0 in the other 380500145 both stored as objects. I ran Regex to clean the columns and then pd.to_numeric, this resulted in one value of 380500145.0 and another of 3.805001e+10. They should both be 380500145. I then attempted;

```
df['SiteReference'] = df['SiteReference'].astype(int).astype('str')
```

But got back;

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

How can i control how pandas is dealing with these, preferably on import?

Comment: You have missing values in your dfs, try calling `df.dropna()` first or `df.loc[df['SiteReference'].isnull()]` to see the errant rows to see if they are salvageable

Comment: Unfortunately I believe there is no easy way of converting a column to `int` when there are `NaN` values (I would love to be corrected). If you cannot drop the corresponding rows as @EdChum suggested, then you could replace them with an `int` value that you know is not in your dataset, make the conversion, and then convert this value back to `NaN`. (For instance if you have only positive integers, replace `NaN` values with `-1`.)

Comment: @IanS that's correct there is no method to represent `NaN` so the OP either has to drop the rows of replace with some suitable value such as `0` or `-1`, after which they can cast the dtype to `int` using `astype`

Comment: @EdChum it would be nice to have the equivalent of `pd.to_numeric(errors='coerce')` for integers. Although in my experience working with floats usually works fine (e.g. for comparisons to integers).

Comment: @IanS float comparison can be dodgy though as the precision can play havoc so you sometimes need to use `np.isclose` which takes an epsilon value for determining whether float values are close to each other

Comment: In this instance @EdChums approach worked as splitting out the nas showed there to be only a small number which eyeball review showed not to be in my study area. This allowed conversion to integer and from there merge could handle the join successfully. Thank you and to IanS for useful background. I'd forgotten the difference between None and NaN, .info() wasn't showing any nulls but it doesn't look for Nones so overlooked this as cause of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perharps the best solution is to avoid that `pd.read` affect the type of this field :

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=',',dtype={'SiteReference':str})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion in the comments, if you want to format floats as integer strings, you can use this:

```
df['SiteReference'] = df['SiteReference'].map('{:,.0f}'.format)
```

This should handle null values gracefully.